# How are some gems added to the OS PATH?

Tags: ruby

Some gems can be invoked directly from the OS command line, like how you run `rails new`. But this doesn't appear to be default behaviour for gems. How is the behaviour activated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RubyGems installs scripts into your OS's `bin` directory for all executable files in your Gem (i.e. all the files listed in the `executables` array of the gemspec).

See for example the section on [Adding an executable](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable) in the [RubyGems *Make your own Gem* guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) or [the documentation of the `executables` attribute in the gemspec reference](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#executables)